# Dealloc in a thread

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, memory, memory-management

In the app there is a list of documents which you can download.

I manage the asynchronous download prosess with the NSURLRequest and a NSURLConnection.
The viewing of the document is managed by a QLPriviewController.

When I download a document and before it is downloaded completely I push back and press another document I get this error:

```
*** -[QLPreviewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3479a0
```

I found the problem but I don't know how to solve it.

In the dealloc method I release the QLPreviewController.
when I remove the release it is working, but I guess its a memory leak then.

Can some one help me with this brain-teaser?

EDIT:

init of the request and connection:

```
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:document.latestVersionURL
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                    timeoutInterval:60.0];

            theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

Comment: can u post more core or just using instruments zombie to detect this dealloc? deals with nsurlconnection sometime hard to understand from memory management side..

Comment: Why would it be a memory leak? it has already released itself which is why you are getting that crash. You are trying to release it again. Can you post code showing how you initiate QLPreviewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a reference to the `NSURLConnection` as an instance variable.

In your dealloc method, before releasing the `QLPreviewController`, call `cancel` on the `NSURLConnection`.

This will stop the request and prevent it from trying to call any methods on the dealloced `QLPreviewController`.

Comment: I get an error: *** -[NSURLConnection cancel]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x393880 I check:if(theConnection)
    {
        [theConnection cancel];
    }